# DataProtectionBuilder.ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault not working in .net 4.7.2

Tags: azure-keyvault, cookie-authentication

`ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault` is not pulling key from `Azure KeyVault` using  `.net 4.7.2.`. But it works well in `.netcore 2.2`

I do the following:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Identity.Application", 
        CookieName = ".AspNet.SharedCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"), 
        TicketDataFormat = new AspNetTicketDataFormat(
        new DataProtectorShim(
            DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\SBH"), (builder) => {
                builder
                    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(
                        "https://test.vault.azure.net/keys/jwt",
                        "ClientID",
                        "ClientScret")
                    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\SBH"));
        }).CreateProtector(
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
            "Identity.Application",
            "v2"))),
        CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager()
    });
}
```

The code runs without any errors / exceptions. But not making call to azure key vault.

What is the Problem?

I have installed these two nuget packages

- `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop`
- `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureKeyVault`

Answer (score 0):

As the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.azuredataprotectionbuilderextensions.protectkeyswithazurekeyvault?view=aspnetcore-2.2#applies-to) said, the `AzureDataProtectionBuilderExtensions.ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault` Method **only apply to asp.net core 2.1 and 2.2**. So it will **not working in .net4.7.2**.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by using AspNetCore with framework pointing to .NetFramework while creating the solution.

With this arrangement, I could use the .AspNetCore functions along with .Net 4.7.2 assemblies for the backward compatibility.

And Used the Regular .NetCore middleware functions for dataprotection like below

```
            services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(container, blobName)
                .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault("KeyUri","ClientId", "ClientSecret")
                .SetApplicationName("Name");
```